# How to register generic behavior correctly using MediatR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mediatr

I saw a couple of videos on youtube with implementation of preprocessing validation/logging or whatever through MediatR pipeline behaviors and decided to try this.

I've ended up with this generic implementation of behavior:

```
public class LoggingPipeLineBehavior<TRequest, TResult>: IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, Result<TResult>>
    where TRequest: IRequest<Result<TResult>>
{
    private readonly ILogger<LoggingPipeLineBehavior<TRequest, TResult>> _logger;

    public LoggingPipeLineBehavior(ILogger<LoggingPipeLineBehavior<TRequest, TResult>> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<Result<TResult>> Handle(
        TRequest request,
        RequestHandlerDelegate<Result<TResult>> next,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Starting request {@RequestName}, {@DateTimeUtc}",
            typeof(TRequest).Name,
            DateTime.UtcNow);
        
        var result = await next();

        if (result.IsError)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Requst failure {@RequestName}, {@Error} {@DateTimeUtc}",
                typeof(TRequest).Name,
                result.FirstError,
                DateTime.UtcNow);
        }
        
        _logger.LogInformation("Completed request {@RequestName}, {@DateTimeUtc}",
            typeof(TRequest).Name,
            DateTime.UtcNow);
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

I use result type pattern in all of my requests. For example:

```
public record CreateArtistCommand(string Name, string? Description) : IRequest<Result<Guid>>;
```

So i've registered this behavior as i had seen on wiki:

```
var assembly = typeof(DependencyInjection).Assembly;
        
        services.AddMediatR(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(assembly);
                configuration.AddOpenBehavior(typeof(LoggingPipeLineBehavior<,>));
            });
```

And nothing happened... MediatR sends requests straight to their handlers bypassing this behavior. I've been debugging it for a hour removing these or those dependencies from container and still no result.

i've also tried this method of registration and nothing works:

```
configuration.AddBehavior(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(LoggingPipeLineBehavior<,>);
```

Am i doing something wrong? How should i register this behavior?

Comment: Instead of using `configuration.AddOpenBehavior` or `configuration.AddBehavior`, register the behavior directly with the `IServiceCollection`.
services.AddMediatR(assembly);
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(LoggingPipeLineBehavior<,>));
after making these changes make sure the requests you are sending are of the type `IRequest<Result<TResult>>`.The behavior registration is being picked up by the DI container put a breakpoint in the constructor of your behavior to check if it's being instantiated

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to wrap the response in `Result`? If you get rid of that, and your endpoints will return non-generic classes, everything will work.

Then your class will look like this:

```
public class LoggingPipeLineBehavior<TRequest, TResult>: IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResult>
    where TRequest: IRequest<TResult>
```

Or if you need specific responses to be handled, then:

```
public class LoggingPipeLineBehavior<TRequest, TResult>: IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, SpecificResponse>
        where TRequest: IRequest<TResult>
```

Comment: I know i can. But i don't want to throw exceptions inside handlers directly. Throwing an exception is very expansive operation.

Comment: You should not throw exceptions to specify bad request. Exception should be thrown only in exceptional case, expecially in web api. Instead, you should produce responses with the appropriate HTTP status codes.

Comment: I didn't mean i want to throw them somewhere else. I use Result type as discriminative union to return result or a list of exceptions (not throwing them!).

Comment: Ok, then I can see two options here:

1. Use middlewares: `IApplicationBuilder.UseMiddleware<>()` with status codes, you can access status code through `HttpContext.Response.StatusCode`

2. Use your approach but replace `Result<TResult>` with `TResult` in `IPipelineBehavior` implementation and use cast in handler, which is also might be expensive for you.

Comment: Oh, i have an idea. Maybe you can use inheritance. Let the `Result` class have only error collection. Inherit all your response types from `Result`. And declare your class like this `public class LoggingPipeLineBehavior<TRequest, TResult>: IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, Result> where TRequest: IRequest<TResult>`